# SSL certificate issue with www

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

I have configured the CName record on GoDaddy to point www to @ and I created an SSL Certificate for mydomain.com.

I have no problem accessing it via https://example.com, but it throws SSL exception

"Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). The certificate is only valid for example.com."

if I access it via https://www.example.com.

What's the issue with that - since I have created the CName mapping for www.

Comment: DNS is assumed to be insecure, so your CName mapping is not given any particular trust. The rule for HTTPS is the hostname used in the URL must be present as one of the subject alternative names in the certificate. The way hostnames are resolved to IP addresses is irrelevant to HTTPS security.

Answer (score 1):

When your browser checks certificate, it just takes what's between `https://` and `/` (if any). Since `www.example.com` does not match the subject in your SSL cert, the validation fails.

You need to check the knowledge base of your CA to generate a proper certificate which would have `www.example.com` listed as the alias in your certificate.